# Completely reset PostgreSQL to default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash, postgresql

**Question**

Is there a way to completely reset a PostgreSQL installation on Linux, so it is in the same state as when I installed it?

**Idea**

I have considered

```
rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/*
rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/backups/*
rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/data/*
```

but perhaps that is not a recommended method.

**Purpose**

This would be handy to get rid of left overs from previous programs that have used it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/233234/69930.

Comment: Drop the cluster... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748644/75033

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should do it - just make sure first that the current configuration actually *does* store the files in those directories.

Once it's done, re-initiate the database:

```
sudo -U pgsql initdb
```

Comment: No, please don't. On Ubuntu at least that'll cause a hideous mess because it expects you to use its own wrapper tools.

Comment: It does? Well, there's one more reason to use some other system, then... Personally I'd vote for FreeBSD, but each to their own.

Comment: @Craig: what sort of mess would it create? I've just used this method on Ubuntu, and [it seems fine to me](http://serverfault.com/a/695343/69930). Would you add some detail to your answer?

Comment: @halfer To start with postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf wont won't be where the ububtu scripts expect. Or they will ignore the ones initdb created and keep using the old ones.

Comment: what if this is a remote database that we've connected to and not one that we've initialized locally?

Comment: @anon58192932 If you don't have access to that server, you can't reset it to the state it was in when it was fresh installed. There are files that may have been edited on that server, which you can't affect via just an SQL connection.

Answer (score 29):

It all depends on how it was installed.

### Ubuntu, from packages (built-in or apt.postgresql.org)

Use `pg_wrapper`. See [the Ubuntu docs for PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL). You want to `pg_dropcluster` all existing Pg clusters, then `pg_createcluster` a clean new one.

Do *not* just delete the data dir and re-initdb.

### CentOS/RH/Fedora, built-in packages

I don't have this installed and can't easily test right now. From memory I think it's safe to just stop the server and delete the data dir.

### CentOS/RH/Fedora, yum.postgresql.org packages

See `/usr/share/doc/postgresql??-?.?.?/README.rpm-dist`.

Stop the server with `systemctl` or the `service` wrapper command, delete the data dir, then run `/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb` (adjusting paths as appropriate for your version).

### Any distro, from EDB installer

Stop the server, delete the data dir and `initdb` a new cluster. See the installer docs.

### From source

Stop server, delete data dir, re-initdb.

### OS X

Homebrew: `brew uninstall postgresql; brew cleanup; brew install postgresql`

Postgres.app? EDB installer? MacPorts?

Find a beer. Drink the beer. Repeat. If this doesn't make the pain go away, get something stronger.

### Windows

- Stop service
- Delete data dir
- re-run initdb using `runas.exe` as the postgres user (pre-9.2) or `NETWORKSERVICE` (9.2+). Or just change the ownership afterwards.

Comment: For OS X, brew uninstall and cleanup does not touch my data dir /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5. (it removes the app in /usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.5, note the "opt" not "var") "rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgresql@9.5" was needed before reinstalling.

Comment: I already deleted the database directory before I knew what I was doing. Any advice for us in that circumstance?

Comment: Okay, I had to use `sudo` to run the `pg_dropcluster` command. In my case: `sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 10 main`

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it best to just remove and reinstall?

That way you'll get the latest version and update any dependences along the way.

Run: sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql

Then: sudo apt-get install postgresql

Comment: This did not remove existing DB + users (as of Postgres 9.5)